# What PHP/Shell Framework can be used to access HTTP-POST/-GET Forms (besides curl)?

Tags: php, perl, http, forms, http-post

I'm searching an abstraction layer from pure HTTP-POST/-GET using curl. It should somehow make it easy to define the Targeted script and it's variables.

I read something exists in the FreeX (german unix/programming magazine), but don't have the named magazine at hand.

What can I do?
Stick with curl?
What alternatives do exist?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

As you tagged you question with "perl", you can use Perl. Try [LWP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP) - popular module, and much more convenient than curl. For more complex tasks, try WWW::Mechanize.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the [HTTP Extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.http.php).  It looks like a pretty complete abstraction implemented over curl.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something more sophisticated, there is the Zend_Http_Client ZF Component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Streams to POST also. I generally prefer that over an extension or even cURL since it's core PHP and more likely to be there.

Though, I build open source software that gets installed on machines where the user has low privileges and likely zero control. Your users' options may be different.